# Strange two empty lines between section and references

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to erase the two empty lines between section and references as follows. It would be very nice to solve this unusual problem. Here's my latex script.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


%% Pick the one corresponding to your system
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries\uppercase}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\bfseries}{\thesection.\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textendash}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\textendash}
\renewcommand{\refname}{}

\usepackage{graphicx} % used to insert the figure
\usepackage{multirow} % used for the table
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, bm}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\hyphenpenalty=10000
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}

\columnsep 1cm
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}

\renewcommand\eqref[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}


\begin{document}

\section{References}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically putting in the references heading twice, once using `\section{References}` and once (invisible, but taking up space) using `\renewcommand{\refname}{}`.  Assuming you want a numbered reference list, you can just do

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{foo,
author={Foo, Bar},
year={2019}}    
\end{filecontents}



\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{document}


\nocite{*}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```